# Why does the Console keep writing the same output for the elements in my array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C# programming. I was trying to create new objects (in my case `StudentInfo` object) and place them in the array `studentArr`.

The array is initialized with a length = 5 and I want to create five `StudentInfo` objects and add them to the array. I don't think it's doing that at all and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

I'm supposed to enter student information through `Console.Readline` for five different students and it's only printing out the first student information.

I'm using struct to access the student info.

Some help will be greatly appreciated!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StudentInfo[] studentArr = new StudentInfo[5];

    int objectNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentArr.Length; i++)
    {
        studentArr[i] = new StudentInfo();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter StudentId, StudentName, CourseName, Date-Of-Birth");

        studentArr[i].firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].birthDay = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].studentID = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].addressLine1 = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].addressLine2 = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].city = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].state = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].zipCode = Console.ReadLine();
        studentArr[i].country = Console.ReadLine();

        objectNumber = i + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < studentArr.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} {1} was born on {2}. Student ID: {3}", 
            studentArr[0].firstName, studentArr[0].lastName, 
            studentArr[0].birthDay, studentArr[0].studentID);

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Address: {0} {1} \n\t {2} {3} {4} {5}.", 
            studentArr[0].addressLine1, studentArr[0].addressLine2, 
            studentArr[0].city, studentArr[0].state, studentArr[0].zipCode, 
            studentArr[0].country);
    }
}

public struct StudentInfo
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string birthDay;
    public string studentID;
    public string addressLine1;
    public string addressLine2;
    public string city;
    public string state;
    public string zipCode;
    public string country;

    // Constructor for StudentInfo
    public StudentInfo(
        string first, string last, string dob, string ID, 
        string address1, string address2, string city, 
        string state, string zip, string country)
    {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.birthDay = dob;
        this.studentID = ID;
        this.addressLine1 = address1;
        this.addressLine2 = address2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zip;
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're always accessing the first array element in your `for` loop, change `studentArr[0]` to `studentArr[i]`

Comment: What does `objectNumber` do?

Comment: Small tip: Since you declare `studentArr[0]` over and over (or `[i]` as suggested), declare a local variable like `var currentStudent = studentArray[0]`.  Or just use a `foreach` loop since you aren't using the index for anything beyond enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing only the first element at 0 by writing studentArr[0]. It should be studentArr[i]

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentArr.Length; i++)
{

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on {2}. Student ID: {3}", studentArr[i].firstName, studentArr[i].lastName, studentArr[i].birthDay, studentArr[i].studentID);
    Console.WriteLine("Address: {0} {1} \n\t {2} {3} {4} {5}.", studentArr[i].addressLine1, studentArr[i].addressLine2, studentArr[i].city, studentArr[i].state, studentArr[i].zipCode, studentArr[i].country);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I fixed the problem. It was the problem with studenArr[0]  and I changed it to studentArr[i] and that fixed the problem. I don't remember why I added objectNumber but I took that off. Thanks again!